# gpflow: Non-Independent Multioutput Kernel

Tags: python, gpflow

I'm trying to implement my own MultioutputKernel (MOK) in gpflow,
however I'm stuck at the Multiple Dispatch for the `(Kernel, Inducing Variable)` combinations.

According to the [docs](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/advanced/multioutput.html), the fallback method for the combination of a `MultioutputKernel` with `InducingPoints` should be calling `fully_correlated_conditional` (via `gpf.conditionals.multioutput.inducing_point_conditional`).

However, I can't get any MOK working with non-independent inducing variables, not even the pre-implemented one.
Here's a minimum not-working example for `SharedIndependent`:

```
######################## toy data
d = 1
X = np.random.normal(0, 10, (100, d))
xx = np.linspace(-10, 10, 200).reshape(-1, 1)
f = lambda x: x ** 2
f_ = lambda x: 2 * x
Y = f(X)
Y_ = f_(X)

Y_combined = np.hstack((Y, Y_))
data = (X, Y_combined)

######################### gpflow stuff
kernel = gpf.kernels.RBF(lengthscales=[1.0] * d)
Z = X.copy()
# create multi-output inducing variables from Z
iv = gpf.inducing_variables.InducingPoints(Z)

MOK_K = gpf.kernels.SharedIndependent(kernel, output_dim=2)

m = gpf.models.SVGP(likelihood=gpf.likelihoods.Gaussian(), kernel=MOK_K, num_latent_gps=2,
                    inducing_variable=iv)

optimizer = gpf.optimizers.Scipy()
optimizer.minimize(
    m.training_loss_closure(data),
    variables=m.trainable_variables,
    method="l-bfgs-b",
    options={"disp": True, "maxiter": 1000},
)
```

This does not work, unless one switches out the inducing points with

```
iv = gpf.inducing_variables.SharedIndependentInducingVariables(
    gpf.inducing_variables.InducingPoints(Z)
)
```

But for my custom non-independent Kernel, I need the fully correlated conditionals.
The error I get is

```
ValueError: base_conditional() arguments [Note that this check verifies the shape of an alternative representation of Kmn. See the docs for the actual expected shape.]
```

It seems in the `inducing_point_conditional` method it tries to "flatten" (to 2d) the kernel matrix to the classical multi-output representation before passing it to `base_conditional`. However, I don't understand where it goes wrong, as the shapes should be fine. They are just as defined in the docs.

What would I have to change to get it running with the fully correlated conditionals?

Answer (score 1):

The issue were the dimensions of the variational distribution parameters, `q_mu` and `q_sqrt`.

One has to manually define them in advance, so that they have the shapes `[N*P, 1]` and `[1, N*P, N*P]` respectively, where P is the output dimension (2 in my example).

Note that this is **slightly different to the docs**, they say `q_mu` has to be `[1, N*P]`.

My code from the question is running correctly with:

```
# [200, 1]    
q_mu = tf.zeros([200, 1], dtype=gpf.config.default_float())

# [1, 200, 200]
q_sqrt = tf.eye(200, dtype=gpf.config.default_float())[tf.newaxis, ...]

m = gpf.models.SVGP(likelihood=gpf.likelihoods.Gaussian(), kernel=MOK_K, num_latent_gps=2,
                    inducing_variable=iv, q_mu=q_mu, q_sqrt=q_sqrt)
```

Comment: Thanks for sorting this out! If this is a bug in the docs, could you submit a PR to fix this?

Comment: @Fabricio can you point to where in the docs it says that shape should be [1, N*P]? I tried to find it but didn't manage. As pointed out by Mark, if that's the case it is certainly a mistake in the GPflow docs and it would be great if you could fix it directly using a pull request! Happy to chat on the [GPflow slack](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/#slack-workspace) if you'd like some help with that.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is just a specific instance where the docs are wrong, so I didn't want to suggest any changes yet.

However, I was anyway planning to do a little notebook Example for a custom MOK at some point (probably for a derivative GP). When I do that I'll check it more carefully.

You can find the docs for that in the rightmost column of the "Implemented combinations" table here:
https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/advanced/multioutput.html#Implemented-combinations