# VGP in "simple demonstration of coregionalisation" with Gaussian likelihood

Tags: gaussian-process, gpflow

In the "[simple demonstration of coregionalisation](https://gpflow.github.io/GPflow/2.9.1/notebooks/advanced/coregionalisation.html)" example in GPflow a VGP is used with Gaussian likelihoods for each GP. Is this approach equivalent to an exact regression model? I was trying to reimplement the example using GPR, but was unsuccessful so far, so I am not sure how to verify otherwise.

Edit:
I was following [this example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73963058/gpflow-2-vgp-model-with-mok-and-multiple-input-throws-valueerror), however in my case I have variable length input/output, i.e. each Xi-Yi pair have different length and own mean functions, by using `mea = gpflow.functions.SwitchedMeanFunction(mean_list)`. kern is a kernel modelled as in the given example by `kern = k1 * coreg` and `coreg = gpflow.kernels.Coregion(output_dim=output_dim, rank=rank, active_dims=[1])`.

Using:

```
m = gpflow.models.GPR([X_augmented, Y_augmented], kernel=kern, mean_function=mea)
```

gives me one reasonable result regressing through the data points and a second one which seems very random and consists of parallel lines not regressing through any data points.

Thanks in advance, appreciate any hint.